# JS iFrame content to trigger iFrame event

Tags: javascript, iframe, event-bubbling

I need the content of an `iframe`(i.e. the `src`) to be able to trigger an `onclick` assigned to the iFrame.

What in particular i need is to get an event of the iFrame's parent triggered, like this:

```
<div onclick='alert("!!")'>
  <iframe src='www.wikipedia.org'></iframe>
</div>
```

... so that every time, when one clicks in the site of Wikipedia (or whichever site on whichever element), to get this `onclick`.

https://jsfiddle.net/s4jk03dg

No libraries.

Comment: [Don't be evil](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clickjacking)

Comment: need that to detect a MMB click .... and it's not for evil